# iOS memory/performance optimization regarding temporary objects

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, ios5, memory-management

I have a method in my code that runs a lot of times.
I need my code to be able to run for hours, so this method will be executed hundreds of times.

The method consists of temporary variables, which are not large.
I wonder what of the following 4 ways will be the best, regarding memory management and performance under ARC:

1) Alloc-init all the temporary objects.
2) Use the "convenience" initializers instead (i.e, [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:...]).
3) Declare those temporary objects as ivars/properties/global, initialize them once in Class +init method and just set them (without initializing) in this method that runs multiple times.
4) Scope the whole method with @autorelease block.

Please explain what will be the impact of each one of them on performance and memory management under ARC project.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you cannot release an object twice that will make the app to crash...

Comment: OK, but how does it answer my question? :)

Comment: I wouldn't use any kind of autorelease as this always sounds like additional overhead. If you want maximum performance, ARC seems to be a bad decision. Just release objects you don't need by hand and you'll be fine.

Comment: @AnatolyAnatoly: Are you sure you're trying to optimize something that really matters? Do you care about the speed of your app, or about its power consumption? And will your really run for hours? (If a user doesn't use his phone or tablet, the app goes into background and is basically stopped.)

Comment: @Codo: My app is one of the permitted background apps according to Apple. It has a background mode key and is supposed to run for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to nil the objects at the end of each loop and then re-init them, theoretically ARC should be releasing the object at this point.

Re-assigning to an iVar, should effectively be inserting the classic setter pattern.

```
if (newVal != iVarVal) {
    [iVarVal release];
    iVarVal = [newVal retain];
}
```

Either way your objects shouldn't be hanging around any longer than they need to be, this is the point of ARC. If you want to be sure, set up a test project and profile it in instruments with the allocations tool and see if the memory usage grows continually, or levels off and at what point it levels off.

For cleanliness of code, I would either declare the variables inside the scope they will be used (ie inside the loop), or possibly just outside the loop and just reassign the value. It's good practice to nil the variable before reassign it.

EDIT

Further to your comment, this is what I consider to be best practice

```
- (void)exampleMethod {
    id variable = nil;
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_LIMIT; i++) {

        // init 
        variable = <alloc/init variable here>

        /* use variable somehow.... */

        // nil variable before reassigning 
        variable = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please clarify some more what is actually the best practice among the four choices?

Comment: For me, best practice would be declaring the variable just outside the loop. Using a convenience method to set the value, then nil-ing out the variable at the end of the loop. I've edited the answer to demonstrate

Comment: Does this mean there will be LOOP_LIMIT variable objects until the autorelease pool will be drained or will the variable will be released in the end of each iteration?

Comment: No, autorelease doesn't really come into it. ARC will analyze your code before compiling it, and add retain/release statements where necessary. Imagine that `variable = nil` is automatically replaced by   `[variable release], variable = nil;` So there shouldn't be a build up of objects. Each one should get released at the end of the loop and a new one created at the start of the next iteration.

Comment: Actually, it seems I do not understand what objects ARC puts into autorelease pool. I though all the object that are initialized with convenience initializer are assigned to the autoreleased pool. I though this is the difference between allocating an object with alloc/init and the convenience initializer

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. Sorry I had overlooked the way the convenience methods were handling releasing the objects their side. The main autorelease pool is run on the main thread, and drained at the end of the run cycle. alloc/init will circumvent this problem. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Regarding execution time for the different approaches, I've created a sample iOS project that measures the average execution time for 4 different methods.

You can test it by [downloading the code from github](https://github.com/gardenofwine/iOSMethodExecutionTimeTest) and substitue the content of the `MethodsToTest.m` class.

From a test I've made, using convenience methods has a slightly better performance (0.004 millisecond better) that the alloc-init way.

Comment: Thank you very much.. and what about @autorelease block and using iVars?

Comment: You'd have to tet it yourself - just implement methods that use iVars and `@autorelease` in `MethodsToTest.m`